# np.vectorize fails on a 2-d numpy array as input

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to vectorize a function that takes a numpy array as input. I have a 2-d numpy array (shape is 1000,100) on which the function is to be applied on each of the 1000 rows. I tried to vectorize the function using `np.vectorize`. Here is the code:

```py
def fun(i):
    print(i)
    location = geocoder.google([i[1], i[0]], method="reverse")
    #print type(location)
    location = str(location)
    location = location.split("Reverse")
    if len(location) > 1:
        location1 = location[1]
    return [i[0], i[1], location1]

#using np.vectorize
vec_fun = np.vectorize(fun)
```

Which raises the error

```
<ipython-input-19-1ee9482c6161> in fun(i)
      1 def fun(i):
      2     print(i)
----> 3     location = geocoder.google([i[1], i[0]], method="reverse")
      4     #print type(location)
      5     location = lstr(location)

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I have printed the argument that is passed in to the fun which prints a single value (the first element of the vector) rather than the vector(1 row) that is the reason of the index error but I'm not getting any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: How about just not using `np.vectorize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vectorize` runs your function on each element of an array, so it's not the right choice. Use a regular loop instead:

```
for row in some_array:
    i0, i1, loc = fun(row)
```

It's up to you as to what you want to do with the output. Keep in mind that your function does not assign `location1` if  `len(location) <= 1`, and will raise an error in that case. It also returns a string rather than a numerical value in the third output.

Once you fix those issues, if you want to make an array of the output:

```
output = np.empty((some_array.shape[0], 3))
for i, row in enumerate(some_array):
    output[i, :] = fun(row)
```

Comment: So, there is no way to run vectorize on each 1-d array of a numpy 2-d array ?

Comment: @A.kumar. No, and there wouldn't be any point. Vectorize does not magically speed up or compile python code. It's just running a glorified loop under the hood anyway.

Comment: I read here (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) that np.vectorize uses the broadcasting rule of numpy ,why is this not possible for a 2-D array ?

Comment: @A.kumar. Because broadcasting has nothing to do with your situation. Broadcasting means that when you supply multiple arrays to a function that accepts more than one argument, the shapes of the arrays will be expanded to match along unit dimensions, so you still end up processing one element at a time, in lockstep, across all the inputs.

Comment: This is bonkers. What is the utility of vectorize if it has less functionality than a loop and provides no speedup?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer. I've never found a use for it.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer there isn't much, although I suppose someone might find the broadcasting behavior handy (although, that could be implemented relatively straightforwadly anyway). But even the docs state "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Answer (score 2):

By this time I think yo have solved your problem. However, I just found a way that solve this and may help other people with the same question. You can pass a `signature="str"` parameter to `np.vectorize` in order to specify the input and output shape. For example, the signature `"(n) -> ()"` expects an input shape with length `(n)` (rows) and outputs a scalar `()`. Therefore, it will broadcast up to rows:

```
def my_sum(row):
    return np.sum(row)

row_sum = np.vectorize(my_sum, signature="(n) -> ()")

my_mat = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [2, 2, 2],
])

row_sum(my_mat)
OUT: array([3, 6])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).